# webkit css resize doesn't work with canvas as child?

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas, webkit

Suppose the following html and css code snippet:

```css
#outer {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: both;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <canvas id="inner"></canvas>
</div>
```

I would expect the div to be resizeable, and in firefox, it is. However in webkit-based browsers such as chrome and opera, it isn't. If I replace the inner canvas with a div however, it works there too. So my question is: why does the canvas element in this case prevent the outer div from beeing resizeable? And how can I work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that the canvas is taking the mouse event preventing the resize. If you consider `pointer-events:none` on canvas it will work:

```css
#outer {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: both;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events:none
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <canvas id="inner"></canvas>
</div>
```

To better illustrate, decrease the size of the canvas a little to avoid the overlap with the resize widget and it will also work:

```css
#outer {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: both;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <canvas id="inner"></canvas>
</div>
```

You can also play with `z-index`:

```css
#outer {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: both;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0; /* mandatory to create a stacking context and keep the canvas inside */
}
#inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position:relative;
  z-index:-1;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <canvas id="inner"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this totally works for me! But out of curiosity, what would one do if having pointer events on the canvas was required?

Comment: @PeaBrain I added a third solution where you can keep height:100%;width:100%